# How to create and append a multi-column list after each iteration through a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, list, iteration

I am trying to create a list (I do not need to see the list, a temporary list is fine) that will have 3 columns. Currently Button1 is pressed and Button1.Content is stored in a ListBox1. Button2 is then pressed and Button2.Content is sent to the same ListBox1. There are many of these Buttons, so it is possible that this action may take place many times. 
After ListBox1 has the content from these buttons (single column), I press an ExportButton which sends the contents of the ListBox1 to a LINQ query where a list is produced.

```
public void SelectPropertyInfo(string Content)
    {
        using (Context con = new Context())
        {
           var query =
                     from o in con.O_TABLEs
                     join p in con.P_TABLEs on o.PN equals p.PN
                     where p.PZ == Content
                     select new
                     {
                         customerFirstName = o.CustomerFirstName,
                         customerLastName = o.CustomerLastName,
                         propertyAddress = p.PropertyAddress
                      };
```

At this point I am sending this data to an XML file.

```
XElement PropertyList =
                new XElement("customers",
                            (from q in query.ToList()
                             select new XElement("customer",
                             new XElement("CustomerFirstName", q.customerFirstName),
                             new XElement("CustomerLastName", q.customerLastName),
                             new XElement("Address", q.propertyAddress))));
PropertyList.Save("S:/customers.xml");
       }
}
```

This all works great as long as I send one row from the ListBox1, however if I send multiple rows, the last query overwrites all previous data, which makes sense. I do not know how to store the data after each iteration through the LINQ query. I know I need to store the data after each row from the ListBox1 is sent and then after all of the rows from the ListBox1 are sent, I want to send the data to the XML file. 
I thought another way to accomplish this was to create a method where I could send the data from the LINQ query, but I still do not know how to store the data each time the LINQ query is run.

```
public void CreateXMLList (string CustomerFirstName, string CustomerLastName, string  PropertyAddress)           
       {
         XElement PropertyList = new XElement("customers",
                                 new XElement("CustomerFirstName", CustomerFirstName),
                                 new XElement("CustomerLastName", CustomerLastName),
                                 new XElement("Address", PropertyAddress));

            PropertyList.Save("S:/customers.xml");
       }
```

I would appreciate any assistance or insight into this matter.

Comment: `/` is not a valid windows path separator.

Comment: Windows still knows how to handle it most of the times.

Comment: You should append the data to the xml file, so: read the file into an `XElelment`, add new "customer" elements to it, and save.

Comment: Gert- Thank you for this, I did not know I could add to the XElement, I only saw the create new, so I made the stupid assumption that I had to create it all at once instead of adding to it after it had been created, my bad, but appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously if you want to store multiple customers in an XML file, you need to store multiple customers in the XML file, and not just the one.

Create `PropertyList` outside your loop over the listbox rows, have it contain one element called `Customers`, and then add one `Customer` element to it in each listbox row iteration (one element for each listbox row).

Then, after the loop is over, save the XML to file.

Also, note that in your current code you're storing one customer in an element called *customers*. That's confusing.

Comment: zmbq- Thank you for the answer. Now I am going to ask a stupid question about scope. When I remove the PropertyList from loop, I get the error indicating the query 'does not exist in current context'. How do I pass the customerFirstName (for instance) out of the loop to the PropertyList, so that it is in the same scope?

Comment: I did not know there was an update for XML files, not real bright.

Comment: You're not actually updating the XML files, just the XML structure in memory. You save it to file, but the updates are done beforehand.